# How do I Modify one of the blocks in the create shipment page of magento admin?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I want to add a simple button in the create shipment page in the order management section of admin.  This button would bring up an external website in another window.  That's pretty much it.  Where is the best place to add this code.  I want it to appear next to the create shipment button.

I know the 'Create Shipment' button exist within a module and I was able to locate where it's added...

```
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Shipment\Create\Form.php
```

But, that is just a class that extends code existing elsewhere.  I don't understand Magento well enough under the hood.  Can someone point me in the right location to add my single link button.

I do at least know enough to move any file I modify into the local folder so that it survives upgrades.  I just need help figuring out that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add a button, you should override the corresponding template file.

You have two options depending on where you need the button appear:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/form.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/items.phtml
```

The "submit" button is in the items.phtml file. You could add your own button next to that one.

Comment: Ah-ha... I was only looking in the app/code/adminhtml and it's sub-folders.  I haven't ever poked around in the app/design/adminhtml area.  Thanks a ton - in retrospect it should have been obvious... but hindsight always is.